# How Can I Suppress Google Data Studio Pivot Table Subtotals When Only One Detail Line Exists

Tags: pivot, report, looker-studio, subtotal

I am trying to leverage a Google Data Studio pivot report template to show sales performance by employee. No problem; however, the report is too-busy in terms of providing a subtotal even if there is only one line to be "totaled".  There is no value-add in such cases, and it is the case most of the time.

I was hoping there was an option in the Style section to allow for such sub-total-line suppression, but I'm not seeing any such options.

I have provided a couple of images which should help convey my story and dilemma.

[image: Data Studio Dimensions in Play]

[image: Sample Report]

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found around this was to just concatenate the columns into one using a calculated field. There is not an option in the style section to remove these *completely.
Although, with some concatenated style rules using regex you may be able to remove the "Total" texts that aren't necessary but that still leaves the actual unnecessary subtotals.